# R: Delete Rows After First "Break" Occurs

Tags: r

I am working with the R programming language.

I have the following dataset:

```
library(dplyr)

my_data = data.frame(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1, 2,2,2) , year = c(2010, 2011, 2012, 2013, 2015, 2016, 2015, 2016, 2020), var = c(1,7,3,9,5,6, 88, 12, 5)) 

> my_data
  id year var
1  1 2010   1
2  1 2011   7
3  1 2012   3
4  1 2013   9
5  1 2015   5
6  1 2016   6
7  2 2015  88
8  2 2016  12
9  2 2020   5
```

**My Question:** For each ID - I want to find out when the first "non-consecutive" year occurs, and then delete all remaining rows.

For example:

- When ID = 1, the first "jump" occurs at 2013 (i.e. there is no 2014). Therefore, I would like to delete all rows after 2013.
- When ID = 2, the first "jump" occurs at 2016 - therefore, I would like to delete all rows after 2016.

This was my attempt to write the code for this problem:

```
final = my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  mutate(break_index = which(diff(year) > 1)[1]) %>%
  group_by(id, add = TRUE) %>%
  slice(1:break_index)
```

The code appears to be working - but I get the following warning messages which are concerning me:

```
Warning messages:
1: In 1:break_index :
  numerical expression has 6 elements: only the first used
2: In 1:break_index :
  numerical expression has 3 elements: only the first used
```

**Can someone please tell me if I have done this correctly?**

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You get the warning because `break_index` has more than 1 value which is the same value for each group so your attempt works. If you want to avoid the warning you can select any one value of `break_index`. Try with `slice(1:break_index[1])` to `slice(1:first(break_index))`.

Here is another way to handle this.

```
library(dplyr)

my_data %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  filter(row_number() <= which(diff(year) > 1)[1])

#     id  year   var
#  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1  2010     1
#2     1  2011     7
#3     1  2012     3
#4     1  2013     9
#5     2  2015    88
#6     2  2016    12
```

With `dplyr` 1.1.0, we can use temporary grouping with `.by` -

```
my_data %>%
  filter(row_number() <= which(diff(year) > 1)[1], .by = id)
```

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: Thank you so much for your answer! Do you know what exactly I was doing wrong? Thank you so much!

Comment: Yes, updated the answer with some explanation about it.

Comment: @ Ronak Shah: Thank you so much! Just to clarify - do you think that my answer was also correct (just not efficient)?

Comment: Yes, I think your answer was also correct and giving the correct answer.